# Truck misfires/backfires/shakes/loses power when cold

Tags: misfire, cold-start, hesitation, backfire

I have a 2003 Dodge Dakota and before the engine warms up it will misfire backfire have low power and sometime shake when accelerating or going up a hill.  after it warms up it doesn't do any of this and run fine. I've changed distributor rotor wires and plugs. Any clue what could be causing this?

Comment: Same issue with my Mercedes b160. I think many cars do that when it's cold. But I'm not an expert, so let's see if someone has the solution to our suffering.

Comment: what engine? 4.7? what do fuel trims look like when cold? any stored codes in the computer? my first thought would be intake gaskets. my second thought is head gaskets.

Comment: 3.9 v6 engine. I don't know the fuel trims, I'll have to get that info. No stored codes.